# Best Practices for Large LaTeX tables with Lots of Text

Tags: pdftex

I often find myself converting large tables, such as the one below, into LaTeX. I was wondering if there are good tools or methods to do this, particularly with the large amount of text in the tables below.

If anyone has any recommendations that would be greatly appreciated :)

[image: Sample Table]

Comment: I don't think "best practices" really falls into the domain of this site, since it becomes too much about someone's opinion.  One option would be to ditch the table format, since that's not really gaining you anything at this point.  You can't really compare across rows or columns when there is that much text in each box.  Maybe a nicely formatted `itemize` environment would be able to also convey that information?

Comment: Thanks @Teepeemm I was kind of leaning that way too.